# Basic Ruby Logic - Returning True or False

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, logic

I am new to Ruby on Rails and stuck on some basic logic to have my Rails **check_in method** return "true" or "false". The code and logic below are working but it is "ugly" and needs refactoring.

```
def check_in
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:token])
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

What is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about refactoring working code are a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help...sorry if my post was off topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `if` condition is already evaluating to the boolean you want, you can simply return it. Furthermore, in Ruby, you don't need to explicitly use `return @user && @user.authenticate(params[:token])`, as the value of the last statement in the method will be automatically used as the return value.

```
def check_in
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  @user && @user.authenticate(params[:token])
end
```

Comment: Technically, to make it behave the exact same as the example code, you would need to do `@user && @user.authenticate(params[:token]) && true || false`...

Comment: Or `!!(@user && @user.authenticate(params[:token]))`